# DateTimeField not shown in a template - django

Tags: django, forms, datetime, format

I have two DateTime Fields in a model:

models.py

```
start_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
end_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
```

i also have a form where i set widgets for above fields:

```
'start_appointment': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': "datetime-local"}),
'end_appointment': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': "datetime-local"}),
```

i have an update view where i want to update appointment's fields for example start_appointment. However when rendering form in a template these two fields are shown as `dd/mm/yyyy --:--, --` meaning values from database not shown, while all the others are rendered with no problem.
From the other hand i can execute the form with no problem and update is successful.

template:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-form-label col-3 text-lg-right text-left">{% trans 'Start Appointment' %}</label>
  <div class="col-9">
   {{ form.start_appointment }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Adding forms.py

```
class AddAppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ['user', 'name', 'appointment_notes', 'seat', 'start_appointment', 'end_appointment']

        widgets = {
            'user': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'appointment_notes': forms.Textarea(attrs={'maxlength': '900', 'class': 'form-control' }),
            'seat': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'start_appointment': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': "datetime-local"}),
            'end_appointment': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': "datetime-local"}),
 }
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: could you please share your form  ?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Sure, i've updated.

Comment: the problem might be  this `'type': "datetime-local"`.are you able to add appointement to the db ?

Comment: try to change your datetime to something like this  `'start_appointment': forms.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', attrs={'class':'datetimefield'})`
        `

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the problem. With format i see the date and time but i'm missing datetimepicker now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem might be this `'type': "datetime-local"`

try this
try to change your datetime to something like this

```
'start_appointment': forms.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', attrs={'class':'datetimefield'})
```

and for datetimepicker you can use something like this

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
    
    
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            flatpickr(".datetimefield", {
                enableTime: true,
                enableSeconds: true,
                dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:S",
            });
        });

</script>
```

you can learn more on Flatpickr here https://flatpickr.js.org/